# How to built a dictionnary from linq query with Id as Key and Data Class as Value in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, dictionary, tuples

I wish to built a dictionnary from a wcf service (this service is hosted on a server).

In my application, every 5 minutes, the distant user ask the service to get this dictionnary. This dictionnary will helps me to see if a message have been displayed on the userscreen with the help of the key.

I'm trying to get this result :

Key(alert_id), value1(alert_title,value2(alert_text)...

A dictionnary with Tuple seems to be a good solution, but I need help for the implementation.

```
public Dictionnary<int, Tuple<Alert>> GetAlertDataItems()
{
    Dictionnary<int, Tuple<Alert>> AlertData = new Dictionnary<int, Tuple<Alert>>();
    var q =
    from p in db.AlertMap.Include(a=>a.AlertLog).Include(a=>a.AlertMode).Includ(a=>a.AlertPriority)
    from t in db.RecipientMap
    where ((p.AlertLog.AlertActive==true)&&(p.AlertID==t.AlertID)&&(DateTime.Now < p.AlertLog.AlertEndDate)
    select p;

    foreach (AlertMap singleAlert in q)
    {...//I'm lost here
    }

    return AlertData;
}
```

Alert Class

```
[DataContract]
    public class Alert
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int AlertId {get;set;}
        [DataMember]
        public string AlertModeCde{get;set;}
        [DataMember]
        public string AlertPriorityCde {get;set;}
        [DataMember]
        public string AlertTitle{get;set;}
        [DataMember]
        public string AlertText{get;set;}
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime AlertStartDate {get;set;}
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime AlertEndDate {get;set;}
        [DataMember]
        public byte AlertActive {get;set;}
    }
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

Linq has a `ToDictionary` method built-in:

```
var AlertData = q.ToDictionary(a => a.AlertId, a => a);
```

in which case your return type should be `Dictionnary<int, Alert>`

Or to just extract the alert title and text into a Tuple:

```
var AlertData = q.ToDictionary(a => a.AlertId, 
                               a => Tuple.Create(a.AlertTitle, a.AlertText));
```

in which case your return type should be `Dictionnary<int, Tuple<string, string>>`

Comment: Thanks ! But I get this error with your first example : Cannot implicitly convert type 'system.Collections.Generic.Dictionnary<int,AlertServiceDev.AlertMap> in 'system.Collections.Generic.Dictionnary<int,AlertServiceDev.Alert>' Maybe I miss something about conversion.

Comment: @mrplume the return type of your function must match the 'value" type (second parameter) of your `ToDictionary` call.  I don't know what you're wanting to return - if it's a `AlertMap` then return that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate on result and add items to dictionary one by one:

```
for(int i=0; i< q.Count(); i++)
{
    AlertData.Add(i,new Tuple<Alert>(q[i]))
}

return AlertData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found a solution :

```
public Dictionnary<int,Alert>GetAlertDataItems()
{
    Dictionnary<int,Alert> AlertDict = new Dictionnary<int,Alert>();
    List<Alert> AlertData = new List<Alert>();

    var q =
    from p in db.AlertMap.Include(a=>a.AlertLog).Include(a=>a.AlertMode).Includ(a=>a.AlertPriority)
    from t in db.RecipientMap
    where ((p.AlertLog.AlertActive==true)&&(p.AlertID==t.AlertID)&&(DateTime.Now < p.AlertLog.AlertEndDate)
    select p;

    foreach(AlertMap singleAlert in q)
        {
            Alert a = new Alert();
            a.AlertId = singleAlert.AlertID;
            a.AlertTitle = singleAlert.AlertLog.AlertTitle;
            ....
            AlertData.Add(a);
        }

   foreach(Alert alert in AlertData)
        {
            if(!AlertDict.Keys.Contains(alert.AlertId))
            AlertDict.Add(alert.AlertId,alert);
        }
   return AlertDict;
}
```

It's not a perfect solution because I get my alertid field twice (one as key and another one in the values), but for testing, it's ok.

Thanks for help !